# Add a new page in OpenCart 3, Journal 3 theme and make it homepage

Tags: php, web, redirect, opencart, opencart-3

I have purchased an OpenCart 3, Journal 3 theme as suggested by a developer who promised to customize the website for me and he quit in the beginning. So I had customized it myself without any code knowledge. Now I wish to add a new page and make it as a homepage. Can can I do it with least coding knowledge?

Comment: What is your OpenCart version? What kind of new page you need? What do you want to show there?

Comment: You can use HTML Content default module.

Comment: I am using opencart version 3. I have created a new layout and I want that layout to be my default opening layout. I have no coding knowledge because it's almost a decade being away from coding and software sector.

Answer (score 0):

If using Journal on OpenCart3 - just download demo data that you like the most and then edit the homepage.

In your journal theme archive you can find a folder **DEMO DATA**. There you will see 11 *.sql* files. Each file fore each specific template. Demonstration of each template here:
https://www.journal-theme.com/

To install demo data in your admin panel go to *Jouranl - System - Import/Export*. On the tab **Import** press **Action** and attach some of those *.sql* files. Done.

More about installing demo data here:
https://docs.journal-theme.com/docs/demos/demo

Now you can go to *Journal - Modules - Title/Text*, and edit homepage text, if there is some on you demo theme. Or add yours.

After adding Text - go to *Journal - Layouts - Home* and add your module with text to any place in Home layout.

**UPDATED**

In OpenCart you can't assign a role of a home page to any other page. There is only one Homepage. You have to configure homepage layout for the "first" page according to your task. **But!** For your "second" page - you can create custom layout and then - go to *Catalog - Information*, add new (or edit the existiong one), and on the editing page go to tab **Design**, and there in *Layout Override* find your custom layout. Now, if you are using SEO URL (Can turn on in *System - Settings*, tab **Server** - SEO URLs) - open tab **SEO** and add your Keyword to this an Information page. Now, the link to this info page will be like `https://yourwebsite.com/keyword`, and the layout of this page will be your custom layout. Use it for "second" page. But Homepage is Homepage, we can do nothing about it.

Comment: Thank you. I have already purchased a theme. And I don't get your point. Can you be lil more descriptive..

Comment: There is non need to know much about coding. If you bought theme - there should be a demo data with it. So you can just download a demo you like and customize it.  According to manual in my answer. This is the easiest way. If all site is ready - there is a Home page layout in Journal - Layouts - Home. All you need to custom - you should setting there, not to create a new home page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have completely customised the layout. Demo datas have been updated. According the theme design, it takes a e-commerce styling. I want it to look like a business website in homepage(I have created a new layout for this but I don't know how to activate it) and existing existing homepage layout as a second page, with a link(button) in new homepage.

Comment: UPDETED an answer for you, read please. Believe, it will solve your problem. If the answer is useful - don't forget to upvote and check it as accepted ;)

Comment: Yup I got it. I actually want that layout Journal->layout -> home as it is. And I want another layout out that.

Comment: Just duplicate Home layout (there is a button in layout list), this will help . Name it "Home 2", and you can use it for your second page (using Information). And then you can do with original Home layout your business landing.

Comment: Yup.. but how to add a link to home 2? I want a button to open home 2. How to do it?

Comment: In was in my UPDATE) Go to Catalog - Information, add new (or edit the existing one), and on the editing page go to tab Design, and there in Layout Override find your custom layout. Now, if you are using SEO URL (Can turn on in System - Settings, tab Server - SEO URLs) - open tab SEO and add your Keyword to this an Information page. Now, the link to this info page will be like https://yourwebsite.com/keyword, and the layout of this page will be your custom layout. Use it for "second" page.